# Abstract algebra notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I am new to learning abstract algebra and using multiple books but the notation varies enough to throw me off. Could someone explain to me the differences between:

$\mathbb{Z}\left\{ p\right\}$

$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$

$\mathbb{Z}_{p}$

Where p is prime. Does the brackets around the p make a difference or are the second and third the same?

Comment: The first one is unknown to me, the second one can either denote the $\;p$-adic integers, or the localization of the integers at the prime ideal $\;(p)=p\Bbb Z\;$ , or the quotient ring $\;\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\;$, and the same with the last one...it all depends on the context and on the author whose book you're reading.

Comment: Most books, especially introductory ones, are kind enough to give a definition or glossary about such notations either in the beginning (if they consider them prerequisites) ore where they first introduce them ...

Comment: I agree with Hagen.  I took linear algebra and, for example, the space of polynomials of n degree over the reals in one book took the notation $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ and in another took $\mathbb{R}_n[x]$  The book should be defining the notations for the concept introduced.